# C++ try and catch block waring: function reaches end of non void function

Tags: c++11, try-catch

I have the following code and I am getting this Error which looks strange to me, as I have catch(...) which is equivalent to default. Am I missing anything? 
Please, let me know.

Basically, I have int run function what should be the return placed to resolve the error??

```
  class AgentLauncher : FSWatcher::Watcher {                                       
    public:                                                                          
        AgentLauncher(bool watch_, std::vector<string>& configFiles_)                
            : watch(watch_), configFiles(configFiles_),                              
              stopped(false), need_reload(false) {}                                  



    int run() {                                                                  
        try {                                                                    
            FSWatcher configWatcher;                                             

            addWatches(configWatcher);                                           
            configWatcher.setInitialScan(false);                                 
            configWatcher.start();                                               

            while (true) {                                                       
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);                        
                opflex::ofcore::OFFramework framework;                           
                Agent agent(framework);                                          

                configure(agent);                                                
                agent.start();                                                   

                cond.wait(lock, [this]{ return stopped || need_reload; });       
                if (!stopped && need_reload) {                                   
                    LOG(INFO) << "Reloading agent because of " <<                
                        "configuration update";                                  
                }                                                                

                agent.stop();                                                    

                if (stopped) {                                                   
                    return 0;                                                    
                }                                                                
                need_reload = false;                                             
            }                                                                    

            configWatcher.stop();                                                
        } catch (pt::json_parser_error& e) {                                     
            return 4;                                                            
        } catch (const std::exception& e) {                                      
            LOG(ERROR) << "Fatal error: " << e.what();                           
            return 2;                                                            
        } catch (...) {                                                           
            LOG(ERROR) << "Unknown fatal error";                                 
            return 3;                                                            
        }                                                                        
    }               

/* some more function */
};
```

Comment: You've got an extra brace after your `catch (...)`.

Comment: oops, it was a typo

Comment: `configWatcher.stop();`  (right before the first `catch`) appears to be unreachable.

Comment: Actually, when I did make clean and compile again, the error disappeared. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting this Error which looks strange to me, as I have `catch(...)` which is equivalent to default. Am I missing anything?

That's true only when an exception gets thrown. When no exceptions are thrown, the function continues execution after all the `catch` statements. There is no `return` statement after them. That's a problem.

Add a `return` statement just before the end of the function.

```
int run()
{
   try
   {
      ...
   }
   catch (pt::json_parser_error& e)
   {
      return 4;
   }
   catch (const std::exception& e)
   {
      LOG(ERROR) << "Fatal error: " << e.what();
      return 2;
   }
   catch (...)
   {
      LOG(ERROR) << "Unknown fatal error";
      return 3;
   }

   // Add this.
   return <something_appropriate>;
}
```